# How to set right query using Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm trying to set GET query using Retrofit, but nothing works

```
@GET("/search/users?q={username}+type:user&page={page}&per_page=100")
    Call<List<User>> getUsers(@Query("username") String username, @Query("page") int page);
```

example query: /search/users?q=Mike+type:user&page=1&per_page=100

Please, help

Comment: What exactly doesnt work, and which retrofit version?

Comment: AFAIK, based on my experience, Retrofit is supposed to build the query parameters for you. So try this instead, `@GET("/search/users") Call<List<User>> getUsers(@Query("q") String username, @Query("page") String page, @Query("per_page") String per_page);` I am not sure how to add `+type:user` yet so unless someone else can chime in and answer that you could make it part of the `username` string.

Comment: It seems that reason is in convertor. I'm getting one user and list of users by searching on GitHub. I have bean class for "User", and retrofit perfectly works for getting one user. And also I need a list of users by searching.But github api returns list of user in array "items". So, how can I set retrofit for parsing list of users from this array "items"?

Comment: Can you post the resulting JSON you're trying to parse?